# node AssertionError on same string

Tags: node.js, v8, chai

I'm using a self native addon in a node script. Here's the snippet.

```
var addon = require('MY_ADDON');
...
var should = chai.should();
addon.run().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log(typeof result);
  result.should.equal('hello');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The log shows:

```
hello
string
{ AssertionError: expected 'hello' to equal 'hello'
    at addon.run().then (C:\...)
    at <anonymous>
  message: 'expected \'hello\' to equal \'hello\'',
  showDiff: true,
  actual: 'hello',
  expected: 'hello' }
```

The addon here is a native c++ module in which the v8::Promise::Resolver will resolve some function result (the hello string). Why I got this assertion error?

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you try it with the expect flavor?
    var expect = require('chai').expect;
    expect(result).to.equal('hello');

Comment: @IstvánRábel Same error. Even result=='hello' is false

Comment: Wow :) Maybe something magical with the c++ part? An extra zero character? Really have no clue, maybe iterate through the characters and print out ascii codes to debug the returned value? (dumb check: length?)